# Parsing complicated list of strings using regex, loops, enumerate, to produce a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, enumerate

I have a long list of many elements, each element is a string. See below sample:

```
data = ['BAT.A.100',   'Regulation 2020-1233',   'this is the core text of', 'the regulation referenced ',
'MOC to BAT.A.100', 'this', 'is', 'one method of demonstrating compliance to BAT.A.100', 

 'BAT.A.120',   'Regulation 2020-1599',   'core text of the regulation ...', ' more free text','more free text', 

 'BAT.A.145',   'Regulation 2019-3333',   'core text of' ,'the regulation1111',
'MOC to BAT.A.145', 'here is how you can show compliance to BAT.A.145','more free text', 
'MOC2 to BAT.A.145', ' here is yet another way of achieving compliance']
```

My desired output is ultimately a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

[image]

Comment: **Can you explicitly define the problem?** Right now you're hoping we'll guess what it is ("as you can see"), which is risky.

Comment: how many columns you can have? Is it the one which you have shown or it can be MOC3 and more also?

Comment: @ggaurav max columns are 5 as shown in example Pandas DF. Only MOC or MOC2

Comment: I assume those texts inside are different except first two columns?

Comment: @Leemosh yes the texts inside are always different. First two columns always BAT.A.\d{3}, the element in the list immediately following is always "Regulation\s\d{4}-{4}, the next sequential element is always strings of text, then, in some cases MOC, random text string, and/or MOC2, random text string, then back to BAT.A.\d{3}

Comment: @Prolle Do you always have MOC when MOC2 exists?

Comment: @Leemosh no, I can have i) no MOC and no MOC2, ii) MOC only, iii) MOC and MOC2

Comment: That makes it a little easier. :)

Comment: `MOC to BAT.A.100`,  `MOC2 to BAT.A.145` will always be in this format `MOC to "Short_ref"`?

Comment: @ggaurav yes that is correct, MOC to 'Short_ref'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the strings may have to be concatenated, I have firstly joining all the elements to single string using `##` to separate the text which have been joined.
I am going for all regex because there would be lot of conditions to check otherwise.

```
re_req = re.compile(r'##(?P<Short_ref>BAT\.A\.\d{3})'
                    r'##(?P<Full_Reg_ref>Regulation\s\d{4}-\d{4})'
                    r'##(?P<Reg_text>.*?MOC to \1|.*?(?=##BAT\.A\.\d{3})(?!\1))'
                    r'(?:##)?(?:(?P<Moc_text>.*?MOC2 to \1)(?P<MOC2>(?:##)?.*?(?=##BAT\.A\.\d{3})(?!\1)|.+)'
                    r'|(?P<Moc_text_temp>.*?(?=##BAT\.A\.\d{3})(?!\1)))')

final_list = []
for match in re_req.finditer("##" + "##".join(data)):
    inner_list = [match.group('Short_ref').replace("##", " "),
                  match.group('Full_Reg_ref').replace("##", " "),
                  match.group('Reg_text').replace("##", " ")]
    if match.group('Moc_text_temp'): # just Moc_text is present
        inner_list += [match.group('Moc_text_temp').replace("##", " "), ""]
    elif match.group('Moc_text') and match.group('MOC2'): # both Mock_text and MOC2 is present
        inner_list += [match.group('Moc_text').replace("##", " "), match.group('MOC2').replace("##", " ")]
    else: # neither Moc_text nor MOC2 is present
        inner_list += ["", ""]
    final_list.append(inner_list)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns=['Short_ref', 'Full_Reg_ref', 'Reg_text', 'Moc_text', 'MOC2'])
```

First and second line of regex is same as which you posted earlier and identifies the first two columns.

In third line of regex, `r'##(?P<Reg_text>.*?MOC to \1|.*?(?=##BAT\.A\.\d{3})(?!\1))'` - matches all text till MOC to Short_ref or matches all the text before the next Reg_text. `(?=##BAT\.A\.\d{3})(?!\1)` part is to taking the text upto `Short_ref` pattern and if the `Short_ref` is not the current Reg_text.

Fourth line is for when `Moc_text` and `MOC2` both is present and it is `or` with fifth line for the case when just `Moc_text` is present. This part of the regex is similar to the third line.

Last looping over all the matches using `finditer` and constructing the rows of the dataframe
`final_df`:

[image]

Comment: I'd say not correct. the element AFTER `MOC to BAT.A.145` should be presented in the table as the desired output says?

Comment: @Leemosh I guess input text and dataframe posted in the question doesn't match,

Comment: @Prolle can you confirm the output looks good based on the input?

Comment: @ggaurav I get ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 7 columns

Comment: if you can check you input text, last two elements I think you have included extra?

Comment: I apologies. I didn't post the sample input text correctly. In reality I have multiple string elements of the list that need concatenation to make up a complete reg text and a complete MOC MOC2 (where they exist)

Comment: oh, then you can update the question then

Comment: @ggaurav I have updated the question but am concerned that I am not doing a good job of explaining this. If you understand then great but I think I may need to take this away and break it down so that I have a clear and explicit question.

Comment: yeah, it is confusing now. You can edit this question itself and define how each of the fields will look. And best thing would be if you post the correct expected dataframe and the exact input., like in the third row after more free text there is no quote

Comment: @ggaurav question is updated now. I have also included the desired pandas DataFrame

Comment: @ggaurav thank you so much for that. Much appreciated.